Solution to the confluent Heun equation with irregular singular point at $z=1$
I want to find a solution to the following ODE
$$
w''(x)+\left(\frac{c}x +\frac{d}{(1-x)^2}\right)w'(x)-\frac{\tilde{q}}{x(1-x)^2}w(x) = 0\tag{1}
$$
on the interval $(0,1)$, satisfying the boundary condition $w(1)=0$. I derived this equation from the Heun equation
$$
w''(x)+\left(\frac{\gamma}x +\frac{\delta}{x-1}+\frac{\epsilon}{x-a}\right)w'(x)+\frac{\alpha\beta x -q}{x(x-1)(x-a)}w(x) = 0\tag{H}
$$
in the special limiting case where $\alpha=0$, $a = 1+A/\epsilon$, $A>0$, $-\delta = \epsilon\to+\infty$. So my is probably a confluent Heun equation with an irregular singular point not at $z = \infty$ as it is usually written, but at $z=1$.
The properties of the solutions of Heun's equation (H) are such that before taking the limit $\epsilon\to+\infty$ for $\delta = -\epsilon <0$ there is a unique linearly independent solution  on the interval $(0,1)$ satisfying the boundary condition $w(1)=0$. This solution can be written in terms of the local Heun function as a one-term expression $C_1 (1-x)^{1-\delta}\mbox{HeunG}(a',q',\alpha',\beta',\gamma',\delta',1-x)$. I entered equation (1) into a mathematical program and got the following solution, expressed in terms of the confluent Heun function
$$
w(x) = C_1\mbox{HeunC}\left(\alpha',\beta',\gamma',\delta',\eta',-\frac1{x-1}\right) + C_2 (1-x)^{1-c}\mbox{HeunC}\left(\alpha',-\beta',\gamma',\delta',\eta',-\frac1{x-1}\right).\tag{sol}
$$
For me, this solution has two problems. First, because the confluent Heun function has a cut in the complex plane from $z = 1$ to $z = \infty$, the solution is complex-valued for $x\in(0,1)$ even though all parameters are real-valued. Second, it is not obvious to me what relation between the parameters $C_1$ and $C_2$ I should take to ensure that the boundary condition $w(1) = 0$ is satisfied. So my question is: is it possible to rewrite (sol) in terms of known special functions as a one-term real expression for $x\in (0,1)$, or can it be a two-term expression but still real, and have this expression satisfy the boundary condition?
